# How does a rails model get connected to the appropriate table in a database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Does rails model use `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionHandler#establish_connection` method to connect to database internally, or is there some other mechanism?

If I write `establish_connection` in my model to connect to a different database, 
will it make a new connection every time a sql query is triggered in database for that model, or will the same connection persist?

I am a bit confused, please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, connections with the database are created via `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection` and retrieved by `ActiveRecord::Base.connection`.  All classes inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base use this connection. If you want some of your models to use a different connection you can add class-specific connections.  Say you need to access data residing in a legacy database apart from the db used by your Rails app.  What you want to do is create a new base class that can be used by models that want access to that legacy data.  For example:

```
    class LegacyProjectBase < ActiveRecord::Base
      establish_connection :other_database_you_want_to_connect_to
      self.abstract_class
      ........whatever else
    end
```

You need to add the `self.abstract_class=true` bit for this to work with subclasses.

For the second question, I'm fairly certain Rails will not recreate a connection on query when done this way because Rails keeps database connections in a connection pool inside the ActiveRecord::Base class instance.  The connection pool is simply a hash object indexed by Active Record.  During execution, when a connection is needed, the "retrieve_connection" method walks up the class hierarchy until a matching connection is found.

Comment: a rake task loads rails environment each time it runs, now will this model will create connection to database each time it runs, what will happen to previous connection?

Comment: please update answer and provide me with authoritative reference if possible.

Comment: The book "Rails4way" has some info. on this.  If you want to be certain you don't have multiple connections kept open when not being used you can use the disconnect! method to close the active connection when finished with each rake task or check if a connection remains open by using the "active?" method.